# How can I produce a join on a substring and an integer in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, I'm trying to join two tables like this.

```
...
join f in ent.FTypes on Int32.Parse(c.CourseID[0].ToString()) equals f.FTypeID
...
```

The first character of the string CourseID is a digit, and FTypeID is an int.

This doesn't seem to work though. The exception message I get is:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

What I want to replicate is the SQL string equivalent (which works fine):

```
join FType f on SUBSTRING(c.CourseID, 1, 1) = f.FTypeID
```

Does anyone have the solution to have to do this in LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Have you tried doing the comparison as a string instead?

join f in ent.FTypes on ss.CourseID[0] equals f.FTypeID.ToString()

Comment: Doesn't work for the same reason.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm not having trouble with this construction in LinqPad. Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Should be EF 4 since I'm working in VS 2010 with target version 4 for the .NET framework.

Comment: A lot of assumptions are being made in the answers, and they are getting invalidated and voted down. I would encourage people to not post what they **think might** work. Post what you **know will** work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather nasty join, but I did some testing in Entity Framework with similar data and arrived at something you can test on yours.

It uses `string.Substring` to grab the first character from your string operand, and then uses a combination of the EF-only method `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` (these methods are found in System.Data.Objects.SqlClient) with a cast to `double`<sup>1</sup> and finally a `string.Trim`<sup>2</sup> for your integer operand.

*I have tested this and confirmed that all functions are supported at least in EF 4. Several other methods proposed or featured in the question do not work, because Entity Framework does not know how to tranlsate them to the appropriate SQL equivalent.*

```
join f in ent.FTypes
on c.CourseID.Substring(0, 1) 
   equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)f.FTypeID).Trim()
```

It produces a SQL join that looks like the following:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[FTypes] AS [Extent2] 
ON ((SUBSTRING([Extent1].[CourseID], 0 + 1, 1)) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(STR( CAST( [Extent2].[FTypeID] AS float)))))) 
OR ((SUBSTRING([Extent1].[CourseID], 0 + 1, 1) IS NULL) AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(STR( CAST( [Extent2].[FTypeID] AS float)))) IS NULL))
```

So based on that, you might want to do some additional filtering as necessary.

Give it a shot and see if that helps solve the problem.

---

<sup>1</sup> The cast to double is necessary because `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` does not have an overload for integer and there is no other single best match, so I force one.

<sup>2</sup> The resultant string needs to be trimmed because the string conversion generates some excess padding.

Comment: Finally something that works! And a really well written answer! Thanks a bunch! I wonder how heavy its impact is on performance though.

Comment: That's a good question and one worth considering. This is not going to take advantage of indexing, but then, your original query in SQL was going to miss at least some of that advantage as well. If you're concerned, do some profiling in this area and see if there is a bottleneck.

Comment: A bit disappointing is that this takes about 50 % longer time than using SQL directly without Entity Framework. Code gets prettier though.

Comment: How are you comparing it? For example, I have found that with some EF queries, the actual SQL generated is efficient, the act of *generating* the SQL is a bottleneck (not saying that's the case here, the query itself doesn't look all that complicated). But *if* it is the SQL, you can capture it and analyze it in SQL Server. If it is the generation rather than the SQL, I'd suggest looking into strategies that deal with that.

Comment: My analysis was by using the very simple Stopwatch in .NET. The program runs the query twice, regardless of method. It does not take 50 % longer as I wrote before... Some of the time save for the SQL method in my first tests may have had to do with caching as I ran the LINQ first in the code. SQL is still consequently slightly faster (2.5s - 3.1s) against (3.0s - 3.5s).

Comment: Here's the full LINQ to Entities query, if you are interested

http://goo.gl/zZ4XC

And the word "fag" has nothing to do with sexuality. It's some danish thing to do with schools. I don't speak danish myself.

Comment: That query looks somewhat complex just based on the grouping, and naturally the rather strange join caused by the substring-to-int match. I'd suggest running your tests over more iterations (release build, optimizations on, no debugger attached) to see if the EF penalty is further amortized or if it is just consistently bigger. That is, if the performance is a point of concern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this worked 8 years ago, but modern **EF6** implementation allows you to add anonymous types, so you can add the conversion to your initial select statements, and then you can just compare that new properties directly in the join.

```
    from c in ent.Courses
    select new { typeId = c.CourseId.Substring(0, 1), c }
    join f in ent.FTypes.Select(t => new { stringId = 
    t.FTypeId.ToString(), t }
    on c.typeId equals f.stringId into ...
```

> **NOTE:** The join-statement does not appear to support ToString() but the select-statements do.

You could also move the CouresId.Substring into the join statement, but that may run less efficiently there.

Results in SQL like this:

```
INNER JOIN [ent].[FTypes] AS [Extent2] ON 
(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Extent1].[nvarchar(max)], 3 + 1, 1)))) =  
CAST([Extent2].[Id] AS nvarchar(max))
```